# Calculate vector gradient without using a Python library

Tags: python

I am trying to find the gradient of the function

```
 f(x) = w1 * x1^2 + w2 * x2
```

where `x` is a vector coordinate `(x1,x2)`.

```
def gradient(w1, w2, x):
    x= (x1,x2)
    gradx1=2*w1*x1 + w2 * x2
    gradx2= w2 + w1 * x1^2
    return (gradx1, gradx2)
```

My code is coming up with a nameError, saying `x1 is not defined` when calling the function:

```
gradient(5, 6, (10,10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first:

```py
x1, x2 = x  # unpack your coord tuple
```

And secondly:

```py
gradx2= w2 + w1 * x1 ** 2 # or gradx2= w2 + w1 * x1 * x1
```

in python `^` is bitwise XOR. Exponentiation is `**`.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a `tuple` which you need to unpack like so:

```
x1, x2 = x
```

Rather than:

```
x = (x1, x2)
```